# Creating bitmap from a drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I am going to be working on an app which requires drag/drop on a `Canvas`. Basically, I want to take a `ShapeDrawable` and convert it into a `Bitmap` which I can have the user drag around the screen. This is a simple exercise in itself.

However, I want to add text inside my shape. Is there a way I can add text to the `drawable` itself then convert to a bitmap? I looked into creating a `TextView` with a drawable as a background.

Is this the best way to do it? I sort of want to avoid creating `TextViews` in my code. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit 2/21/2013:

In response to JustDanyul's post I have the following code:

```
int width = 40;
int height = 40;
Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Resources res = context.getResources();
Drawable shape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.miss_scarlet);
shape.draw(canvas);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawText(gameToken.getDbName(), 5, 5, paint);
```

My drawable is not showing up when I draw the bitmap on another canvas.  The drawable itself is fine (I tested it as a background to a TextView).  The text shows up.  Am i missing something in this code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Edit #2  2/21/2013:

I added:

```
shape.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

to my code and now the drawable appears but my text is gone (or just hidden).

Comment: shape.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()); resolved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try something like this, first, create an empty bitmap:

```
int w = 500  
int h = 500; // or whatever sizes you need
Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, config);
```

Next step, create a new canvas instance, which renders onto your newly created bitmap

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Now, you can draw the ShapeDrawable onto your empty bitmap using the ShapeDrawable's draw method

```
myshapedrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Finally, you can use the drawText method of the canvas instance to draw your text on the canvas.

Comment: this would add shape.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()); for "Shape in xml" specially otherwise will not work